# Why do I get different output from gdal2tiles vs. maptiler?

Tags: gdal, cartography, tiles, generate-tiles, gdal2tiles

I am trying to generate map tiles using gdal2tiles for an area much larger than MapTiler can handle.  However, my tile caches are not showing up on the maps.  I checked gdal2tiles by running the same file through it and MapTiler - and the outputs come out differently.  Here's my gdal2tiles command:

> /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/1.9.0/bin/gdal2tiles.py -p mercator --s_srs
>   3857 -z 1-9 -v  myFile.tiff

For instance, in the maptiler output, I get the file

> 9/85/197.png

While gdal gives me different files, like

> 9/85/313.png

The output should be identical, right? Is there something I'm missing?  My projection on the original file is definitely correct.  I have also tried gdal2tiles with 900913.  I am running gdal2tiles on MacOS X Mountain Lion, gdal 1.9.0.

Comment: check out your profile whether mercator or geodetic. it looks like your first output is mercator and second is geodetic.

Comment: That's interesting.. but as you can see, I am calling gdal2tiles.py with the -p mercator argument, and mercator is also the default anyway.  Do we think that that gdal2tiles could be broken in this reqard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDAL2Tiles: MapTiles from BSB/KAP are Switched](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/gdal2tiles-maptiles-from-bsb-kap-are-switched)

Comment: It is completely a duplicate and worked fine with your tip! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It's because gdal2tiles generates the tiles in TMS format. You need to enable it on your map or do a small calculation on the fly in order to display the tiles.

Comment: `maptiler` have `-tms` switch to produce results same as `gdal2tiles.py`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the difference between TMS and XYZ/WMTS addressing of the same mercator tile.

See the detailed description and mashup I made at:

http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

GDAL2Tiles renders always TMS.

The scripts and equations for conversion of the flipped y-coordinate are mentioned in the MapTiler User Group on Google Groups.

If you render the map tiles with the new MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com/) you can choose whether you want TMS or XYZ/WMTS addressing of the tiles. This option is available under the "Advanced options" button.