# GDAL2Tiles: MapTiles from BSB/KAP are Switched

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

As an example I have a BSB file from NOAA which is a navigational map. The map has a SRS of WGS84 and a Mercator projection.

I initially translate the file from BSB format to GTiff format using the following command:

gdal_translate -of GTiff 18554_1.kap noaa.tif

I can view this GTiff file using Paint Shop Pro quite fine. I then translate the file from GTiff format to VRT format using the following command:

gdal_translate -of vrt –expand rgba noaa.tif noaa.vrt

I then try to generate a tile matrix set using the following command:

gdal2tiles.py noaa.vrt tiles_folder

Where the map tiles are located in tiles_folder. If I try to open the openmaps.html or google.html, the map zoom in and out looks **good**. However, on tiles generator like MBTiles, I see tiles **swap**. See the image below. I am pulling my hair off to get the tiles to line up. I am guessing it is projection error. I am not understanding those projection types. It would great someone can explain it while finding the error. I am planning to use on a tiling [airplane maps/charts app](http://airplanegroundschools.com/iphone/airplane-navigation-ifr-high-charts-iphone.php) like this. By the way, on GDAL how do I specify the BSB (reference) file that is associated with KAP (data) file? I have seen cases where only one BSB file referred by multiple KAP files.

[image: Gdal2tiles.py Tile Image Swaped]

Comment: It might be more revealing to characterize the problem not as a "swap" but as a top-to-bottom *reversal* of the tiles.  That suggests @Andre Joost's answer may be on target.

Comment: As you say, the .bsb file is a reference file. It is quite common for the bsb charts to have multiple 'panels'. One .kap file for each panel and one bsb for the whole 'chart'. I think it is doubtful that gdal will ever use the .bsb file as it is primarily concerned with imagery, but then again it is kind of like a vrt...kind of. so maybe someday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed that gdal2tiles numbers the tiles from south to north (according to the TMS specification), while Openstreetmap and others do it from north to south. For my personal use, I changed the code of gdal2tiles to get it right again.

See also: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal2tiles-tiles-in-wrong-hemisphere-and-or-Openlayers-problem-td3742809.html

---

**EDIT**

This is what I changed in Version 19288 2010-04-02:

line 1186, insert one line:

```
ty1=(2**tz - 1) - ty
```

before

```
tilefilename = os.path.join(self.output, str(tz), str(tx), "%s.%s" % (ty1, self.tileext))
```

line 1330, insert

```
ty2=(2**tz - 1) - ty
```

before

```
tilefilename = os.path.join( self.output, str(tz), str(tx), "%s.%s" % (ty2, self.tileext) )
```

line 1363, insert

```
y2=(2**(tz+1) - 1) - y
```

before

```
dsquerytile = gdal.Open( os.path.join( self.output, str(tz+1), str(x), "%s.%s" % (y2, self.tileext)), gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

Line numbers may have changed in current gdal 1.10.0.

Comment: how do you change the code in gdal2tiles.py.  I am not good at python.  I am not sure what sections on gdal2tiles.py where I need to edit the code.

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: Andre, I will let you know as soon as I make above changes to gdal2tiles.py. Thank you so much for doing all that effort to identify lines of code needs to be changed.

Comment: @AndreJ, thank you so much for this answer - I was having issues getting tiles to work in ArcGIS Online, and your suggested edits worked for me.

For anyone else who encounters this issue I also found an updated gdal2tiles.py file which includes support for both TMS and XYZ tile naming formats, along with some other enhancements.  It can be found here:

https://github.com/pramsey/gdal2tilesp

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with using [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/), and I resolved it by setting the tms flag to true (no script changes required). See http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tms.