# gdal2tiles-leaflet producing bad tiles

Tags: leaflet, geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles

I am using gdal2tiles-leaflet in an attempt to generate a tileset for a map renderer I'm working on, however, the resulting tileset appears to be completely misaligned and won't render properly in Leaflet.

The source data is the [NASA Visible Earth bathymetry dataset](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73963/bathymetry). It is made up of several GeoTIFF tiles, which I have stitched into a single large map using gdal_merge.

In examining the resulting PNG files, I noticed that the map does not fill the entire image, as shown below for the 0 layer:

[image: Broken 0 layer]

I assumed this to be due to the original dataset not being evenly divisible by 256 and that it was normal, however, upon loading the tileset into my web page, it showed the same problem, namely that the tile doesn't fill the view properly nor align with other layers:

[image: Broken leaflet map view]

Suspiciously, the leaflet map view also shows the same "1/3rd" fill as the 0 png. Zooming in fills the screen, but still doesn't align with the vector shoreline data (i.e. lat/lons are off in the tileset).

I confirmed that the shoreline vector data (green) is the correct render by placing a marker at a known lat/lon and observing that it was in the correct place for the vector data but not the NASA bathy data.

Investigating further, I noticed that the kml data files appear to have garbage values in the LatLonAltBox tag, see this excerpt from 0.kml and note the *north* and *east* tags:

```
  <Region>
      <LatLonAltBox>
        <north>456.13318687999998</north>
        <south>-89.99992800000001</south>
        <east>366.13311487999999</east>
        <west>-180.00000000000000</west>
      </LatLonAltBox>
      <Lod>
        <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
        <maxLodPixels>2048</maxLodPixels>
      </Lod>
    </Region>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <drawOrder>1</drawOrder>
      <Icon>
        <href>0.png</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>456.13318687999998</north>
        <south>-89.99992800000001</south>
        <east>366.13311487999999</east>
        <west>-180.00000000000000</west>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
```

Similar values from doc.kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Nasa_big_chungus.tif</name>
    <description></description>
    <Style>
      <ListStyle id="hideChildren">
        <listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType>
      </ListStyle>
    </Style>
    <NetworkLink>
      <name>0/0/0.png</name>
      <Region>
        <LatLonAltBox>
          <north>456.13318687999998</north>
          <south>-89.99992800000001</south>
          <east>366.13311487999999</east>
          <west>-180.00000000000000</west>
        </LatLonAltBox>
        <Lod>
          <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
          <maxLodPixels>-1</maxLodPixels>
        </Lod>
      </Region>
      <Link>
        <href>0/0/0.kml</href>
        <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
        <viewFormat/>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
      </Document>
</kml>
```

I don't know if this is a red herring or indicative of a problem in creating the tileset.

However, the geotiff data in the merged input file appears to show nothing strange, as seen with gdal_info:

```
]$ gdalinfo Nasa_big_chungus.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Nasa_big_chungus.tif
Size is 43200, 21600
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.008333330000000,-0.008333300000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -89.9992800) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 89d59'57.41"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9998560,  90.0000000) (179d59'59.48"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9998560, -89.9992800) (179d59'59.48"E, 89d59'57.41"S)
Center      (  -0.0000720,   0.0003600) (  0d 0' 0.26"W,  0d 0' 1.30"N)
Band 1 Block=43200x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I assumed it was a coordinate issue, and explicitly ran gdal2tiles-leaflet with the appropriate spatial reference system for WGS84:

```
$python ../gdal2tiles-leaflet/gdal2tiles-multiprocess.py -l -s EPSG:4326 -p raster -z 0-7 -w none Nasa_big_chungus.tif tiles
```

But to no avail.

Since my JavaScript Leaflet code is extremely simple and more or less a copypasta of the tutorial code, I'm thinking the issue must be in how I'm generating the tiles.

However, for reference, the leaflet code is here:

```
var map = L.map('map', { crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857, minZoom:0, maxZoom:9}).setView([0, 0], 2); // Set initial view to center of the world


    var img = [43200,21600]

    var rc = new L.RasterCoords(map, img); 

    map.setMaxZoom(rc.zoomLevel())
    console.log("Max zoom: ", rc.zoomLevel())
    console.log("Max bounds: ", rc.getMaxBounds())

    map.setView(rc.unproject([img[0], img[1]]),2)

        
    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Derp.',
      noWrap: true,
      bounds: rc.getMaxBounds(),
      maxNativeZoom: rc.zoomLevel()
    }).addTo(map);  
  
           
    // Add shorelines layer
    var shorelinesLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_110m_coastline.geojson", {
        style: function (feature) {
            return {
                color: 'green',
                weight: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0
                };
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

Thinking there might be something wrong with the NASA bathy data, I also tried the *much* larger [GEBCO dataset](https://gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/#global), but got the same problem, namely the 2/3rd width 1/3rd height problem with the png tileset not lining up with the correct lat/longs.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Is the problem in how I'm generating the tiles or in the JavaScript used to render with Leaflet?

Comment: ...and how are you actually calling `gdal2tiles` to generate the tiles?

Comment: @IvanSanchez It's in the post right after where I show the output from gdal_info.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked it. Are you using https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet or https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html ? What's the version of `gdal2tiles`?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I'm using gdal2tiles-leaflet. I was under the impression that the standard gdal2tiles can't output leaflet compatible tiles.

Comment: Gdal2tiles creates a Leaflet viewer by default https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#cmdoption-gdal2tiles-w. What makes you think that the tiles are incompatible?

Comment: @user30184 the fact that the gdal2tiles-leaflet repo even exists? When did leaflet support get added to the main gdal repository?

Comment: @user30184 Running with the tip of the GDAL repo with "-w leaflet" gives essentially the same problem. The only difference is the resulting tiles are on the bottom of the image instead of the top, but they still don't render properly in a browser.

Comment: Your input image CRS is `EPSG:4326`. Does `gdal2tiles` reproject image to `EPSG:3857` when creating tiles?

Comment: @TomazicM I've tried multiple coordinate systems to no effect. Setting the CRS in the leaflet map creation doesn't seem to change anything. Not sure why.

Comment: @stix If "tiles are on the bottom of the image", then read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66986/gdal2tiles-py-generates-wrong-tiles-maptiler-the-right-ones/346407#346407 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631573/how-to-calculate-tiles-coordinates-in-leaflet-to-request-tms-server

Comment: Try setting map `crs` option to `EPSG:4326`.