# Tiling from complex, multi-step GDAL VRT?

Tags: python, gdal, vrt, tiling

I've got 1002 ~100 MB (5000'x5000') .tif files in a state plane (transverse merc) projection comprising a county-wide, 1-ft aerial dataset. After two days, gdal_merge.py is only at 93 of 1002. And when it's done, I'll still need to apply a mask/cutline, then reproject to EPSG:3857 *before* I can even start tiling. So I'm trying to find a quicker approach..

I'm relatively familiar with the VRT format and this idea of [lazy evaluation](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2010/02/18/lazy-raster-processing-with-gdal-vrts/), but after several rounds of testing, I'm not convinced the workflow I'm pursing is more efficient.

Here's the workflow I'm asking about (skipping the mask/cutline for now):

- gdalbuildvrt --> merge the 1002 .tif files -------------> outputs mosaic VRT
- gdalwarp -----> transform to EPSG:3857 ------------> outputs web merc VRT
- ..start tiling against the 2nd-generation VRT..

The tiling script I wrote in Python (which may be a weak-link in its own respects) is definitely capable of reading the VRT. Small-area windows render in a few seconds, still longer than I'd like. But large area windows take quite a long time. As I'm writing on this, I'm waiting on a sample z=12 tile to render.. I bet it's already eaten 20+ minutes.

Ultimately, my goal is to create 256x256 tiles in the OSM scheme, like you'd get out of Mapnik, but using a Python/GDAL-only approach. ..I've deemed this necessary because I can't get Mapnik to properly consume my 2nd-generation VRT.

My python script is creating the OSM grid properly---I sniped some code from a Mapnik utility (generate_tiles.;y), and I'm getting proper cell coordinates for my raster. But I question whether or not my `ReadRaster()` / `WriteRaster()` implementation is efficient.. I'll paste in that part; values are hard-coded for my sample z=12 tile..

```
def getTileData():
    gdal.AllRegister()
    dataset = gdal.Open('C:/xGIS/Aerial/3857/2009_1ft_od_3857.vrt', GA_ReadOnly)
    bands = dataset.RasterCount
    band_type = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).DataType

    memDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM')
    memDS = memDriver.Create("TEMP", 256, 256, bands, band_type, [])
    memDS.SetGeoTransform( [94490, (256.0/(121069-94490)), 0, 96198, 0, 256.0/(96198-94490)] )

    for b in range(1, bands+1):
        s_band = dataset.GetRasterBand( b )
        t_band = memDS.GetRasterBand( b )
        data = s_band.ReadRaster( 94490, 69618, 121069, 96198, 256, 256, band_type )
        t_band.WriteRaster( 0, 0, 256, 256, data )

    createDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('PNG')
    createDS = createDriver.CreateCopy("C:/xGIS/RichlandCounty/Aerial/SCRich09_1ft/3857/tiles/snap_2.png", memDS)
    createDS = None
    memDS = None
```

Does anyone have any insights or reactions that might help me get results quicker?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it helps you, but this was my workflow to tile 2GB of 300 Dutch Topo maps to OSM compatible zoomlevel 15 and 16:

- Create vrts for each tif and expand indexed colours to RGBA:

> for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25*.tif) DO gdal_translate
>   -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\%%~nN.vrt

- Create an index vrt for all files:

> gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index25.vrt NL25*.vrt

- Use gdal2tiles to define source CRS, create zoomlevel 16, and mosaic that to zoomlevel 15:

> gdal2tiles --s_srs EPSG:28992 --zoom 15-16 index25.vrt tiles

I had to make some minor changes to gdal2tiles to enable correct tile numbering, as described here: [GDAL2Tiles: MapTiles from BSB/KAP are Switched](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/gdal2tiles-maptiles-from-bsb-kap-are-switched)

It took several days, but python just is not that quick...

Comment: Thanks for your input here. I tried using gdal2tiles first, actually and found it to be terribly slow, so I was preferring to avoid it. In the past I've always used gdal_retile, which is much faster, but _retile doesn't render to the OSM/Mapnik folder structure so I'm exploring other options. On the final analysis I may cave and go with gdal2tiles, though.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the vrt file.
Install Mapserver/gdal.
Create a map file that references the vrt file. Get wms working.
Install mapproxy.
setup mapproxy to act as a client to Mapserver wms
Query mapproxy for your tiles.

if you want to pre-generate all the tiles you will need the code to query mapproxy for them.
The problem with the above is that as you go 'up' in the tile pyramid, mapserver/gdal will have to reference all 1002 of your 100MB files to create that one 256x256 tile. you could create a subsample layer of merged tifs to solve for that and add them to the mapfile, but that requires more work.
The workaround to that is to use mapproxy's ability to read the TMS it just created.  You can have mapproxy create lets say level 12 from level 13 etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. We put this one on the back-burner while pursuing other projects, but I'd still like to come to a solution some day. Yours is a good suggestion but unfortunately Mapserver isn't an option for us. However we do have a Geoserver instance, do you think your approach would translate smoothly to Geoserver? I haven't researched that angle very much, as I was initially hoping to pre-tile everything.

Comment: Yes Geoserver can work. Geoserver has something called the ImageMosaic plugin. Also MapProxy has a seeding tool that will automate creating the tile pyramid.