# OpenLayers 2.13 : How to display a local tiled raster?

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, tiles

I am trying to display (on OpenLayers 2.13) a local tiled raster I made with gdal2tiles.py. Unfortunately it's all blank or pink. Here is my layer definition:

```js
var tiles = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("Local tiles", "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {
    isBaseLayer: true,
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    maxExtent: [-75.1729846, 39.9439032, -75.1529085, 39.9599679]
});

map.addLayer(tiles);
```

What is wrong?

Here is a link to my OpenLayers test page : http://popopopopo.voila.net/index.html

And here is the original image: http://popopopopo.voila.net/raster.tif (EPSG: 3857)

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Can you open the tiles directly? For me, it redirects in some strange way (possibly your hosting provider).

Comment: Yes I can open tiles directly like this http://popopopopo.voila.net/tiles/14/4770/10178.png if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Gdal2tiles numbers the tiles from South to North (according to the OGC TMS sepcification), while OSM numbers from North to South (like Google and bing does it).

I described here what I changed to make it numbering in correct (OSM) order:

[GDAL2Tiles: MapTiles from BSB/KAP are Switched](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/gdal2tiles-maptiles-from-bsb-kap-are-switched)

If I load the OSM tile with the example numbers you gave above, I get one from the Pacific off the coast of Chile, at -75° East -39.95° North. I guess that is not what you intended with your extent, which should direct to Philadelphia.

The mapquest tiles you show in your map are in the range of

http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/14/4770/6205.jpg

So you have to make sure your self rendered tiles have the same number if they should appear in the same place.

Leaflet has an option to set `tms=true` for tiles generated according to the TMS specification. Openlayers seems to lack this opportunity yet.

See also:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles

http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~poenisch/vortraege/osm/slide-4-5.html

---

**EDIT**

It is possible to use the TMS numbered tiles by extending the Openlayers TMS call, see my answer here:

[Add TMS layer to OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86280/add-tms-layer-to-openlayers)

Comment: Indeed, what you say is worth to know because I didn't know it was upside down with gdal2tiles. I am now testing maptiler instead as suggested. I keep you informed if I managed to display successfully the raster...