# Add TMS layer to OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, tile-map-service

I have found some examples but haven't managed yet to adapt them to my needs...

I have an image that is served as TMS (tiles already statically rendered): http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/tiles

What would be the right syntax to display it in OpenLayers?

On this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/tms.html It looks quite different, as if the tiles are dynamically rendered by a python script...

I tried something like this

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS",
    "http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/", {layername: 'tiles', type:'jpg'} 
);
```

But no success so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you serve is not a TMS service acording to Openlayers specification. They expect a service which can be questioned for tiles similar to WMS.

Unfortunately, your tiles follw the OGC naming convention, and not OSM-like. See my answer here to number the tiles correctly:

[GDAL2Tiles: MapTiles from BSB/KAP are Switched](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/gdal2tiles-maptiles-from-bsb-kap-are-switched)

**EDIT**

I finally managed to load the data into QGIS using the TileLayer Plugin. That allows to switch the layer numbering between OGC and OSM.

This is my entry in the config file:

```
khorog  khorog  http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg  0   12  16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

Note that tabs have to be used as delimiters. And this is the result:

[image]

with OSM in the background and your tiles transparently overlayed (which Openlayers plugin will do not either).

---

**Last Edit**

I finally got success with your Maptiler tiles by using the Openlayers page that was created by Maptiler. They hacked the getURL to respect the inverse numbering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>"
          <head>
            <title>khorog</title>
            <meta http-equiv='imagetoolbar' content='no'/>
            <style type="text/css"> v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                html, body { overflow: hidden; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Geneva,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; }
                body { margin: 10px; background: #fff; }
                h1 { margin: 0; padding: 6px; border:0; font-size: 20pt; }
                #header { height: 43px; padding: 0; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #888; }
                #subheader { height: 12px; text-align: right; font-size: 10px; color: #555;}
                #map { height: 95%; border: 1px solid #888; }
            </style>
            <script src="OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                var mapBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds( 71.5, 37.4, 71.6, 37.5);
                var mapMinZoom = 12;
                var mapMaxZoom = 20;

                // avoid pink tiles
                OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
                OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";

                function init(){
                var options = {
                    controls: [],
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    units: "m",
                    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34)
                    };
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);


                // create OSM/OAM layer
                var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "OpenStreetMap",
                    "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/",
                    { type: 'png', getURL: osm_getTileURL, displayOutsideMaxExtent: true, 
                      attribution: '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>'} );


                // create TMS Overlay layer
                var tmsoverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS Overlay", "http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/tiles/",
                    {   // url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.',
                        type: 'jpg', getURL: overlay_getTileURL, alpha: true, 
                        isBaseLayer: false
                    });
                if (OpenLayers.Util.alphaHack() == false) { tmsoverlay.setOpacity(0.7); }

                map.addLayers([osm, tmsoverlay]);

                var switcherControl = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
                map.addControl(switcherControl);
                switcherControl.maximizeControl();

                map.zoomToExtent( mapBounds.transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection ) );

                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());
            }

            function osm_getTileURL(bounds) {
                var res = this.map.getResolution();
                var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
                var y = Math.round((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
                var z = this.map.getZoom();
                var limit = Math.pow(2, z);

                if (y < 0 || y >= limit) {
                    return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
                } else {
                    x = ((x % limit) + limit) % limit;
                    return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
                }
            }

            function overlay_getTileURL(bounds) {
                var res = this.map.getResolution();
                var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
                var y = Math.round((bounds.bottom - this.tileOrigin.lat) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
                var z = this.map.getZoom();
                if (mapBounds.intersectsBounds( bounds ) && z >= mapMinZoom && z <= mapMaxZoom ) {
                   //console.log( this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type);
                   return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
                } else {
                   return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
                }
            }       

           function getWindowHeight() {
                if (self.innerHeight) return self.innerHeight;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
                    return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                if (document.body) return document.body.clientHeight;
                    return 0;
            }

            function getWindowWidth() {
                if (self.innerWidth) return self.innerWidth;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                if (document.body) return document.body.clientWidth;
                    return 0;
            }

            function resize() {  
                var map = document.getElementById("map");  
                var header = document.getElementById("header");  
                var subheader = document.getElementById("subheader");  
                map.style.height = (getWindowHeight()-80) + "px";
                map.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                header.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                subheader.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                if (map.updateSize) { map.updateSize(); };
            } 

            onresize=function(){ resize(); };

            </script>
          </head>
          <body onload="init()">
            <div id="subheader">Generated by <a href="http://www.maptiler.org/">MapTiler</a>/<a href="http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/">GDAL2Tiles</a>, Copyright &copy; 2008 <a href="http://www.klokan.cz/">Klokan Petr Pridal</a>,  <a href="http://www.gdal.org/">GDAL</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.osgeo.org/">OSGeo</a> <a href="http://code.google.com/soc/">GSoC</a>
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" >resize()</script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

This works with all browsers.

Comment: You can find the structure here: http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/tiles/ I used Maptiler (http://www.maptiler.org/) to create the tiles. In JOSM, I can display it with http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/tiles/{zoom}/{x}/{-y}.jpg
I think the problem comes from the "y" coordinate: for some reason, I have to use "-y" in JOSM. So with "y" in OpenLayers, incorrect tile names are requested. But I don't get it to work, neither with "${-y}" nor with "-${y}"

Comment: In JOSM, I have managed to see the tiles at the right place with {-y}, but that syntax is not valid for Openlayers. Maptiler should have a switch to number the tiles correctly (that is OSM-like). I prefer to hack gdal2tiles for it. See my extended answer.

Comment: I see... I would actually be quite happy if I don't have to recreate the tiles... According to what you say, I would assume that using OpenLayers.Layer.TMS() instead of OpenLayers.Layer.OSM() might do the job, because it would use the OGC system instead of the OSM one? But the parameters are obviously different

Comment: No, Layer.TMS() expects a service like WMS, which you do not have. Openlayers can not handle your tile naming, but leaflet does: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66986/gdal2tiles-py-generates-wrong-tiles-maptiler-the-right-ones

Comment: Ok, I have modified GDAL2tiles.py, regenerated the tiles (available here: http://humadat.alwaysdata.net/tms/khorog/tiles_osm/ )and it works correctly in JOSM without the "y flip". But for some reason it doesn't display in OpenLayers http://henriod.info/khub2/khub2_new.html (base layer "Khorog high-res") What is weird is that Firebug seems to receive the tiles...

Comment: Same here, but only with Firefox. Internet Explorer and K-Meleon show the tiles. This must be a security restriction in Firefox.

Comment: Ok... in any case, thanks for you help, it nailed it!