# render geotiff tiles as a map layer

Tags: qgis, google-maps, maps

i have the following problem: i have downloaded tiff files with gMapMaker and transformed them to GeoTiff using the associated .map files in QGIS. now i want to render these GeoTiff files to use them as a map (like using Google Maps API) and then apply some geographic info (as an SVG element on a particular geographic point) for example using d3.js or OpenLayers.. The important thing is that i have to do all of this offline (yes, i'm trying to re-create a sort of Google Maps offline)..
until now, i tried to use Javascript but i didn't find any library to load GeoTiffs; moreover i can use also other languages (i have no restrictions from this point of view)... can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few options.

One approach could be to use [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) or [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) in combination with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you may also want to consider looking at [TileCache](http://tilecache.org/), [mod_tile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) and/or [TileLite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tilelite/0.1.4).  These are all tile caching tools.  They all have Python APIs.

All of these tools are free and using them (possibly in combination with PostGIS) will allow you to build a solution along the lines you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it totally offline, you can create Google-like tiles with gdal2tiles.py, store them in the usual folder hierarchy, and display them with Openlayers or Leaflet.

You have to take care about the tile naming. gdal2tiles.py uses the official TMS standard, while Google (and Openstreetmap) do not.

I have explained here: [GDAL2Tiles: MapTiles from BSB/KAP are Switched](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/gdal2tiles-maptiles-from-bsb-kap-are-switched)

how to modify gdal2tiles.py to overcome this.